# Application for resizing an image by reducing dimensions precisely?

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, image-processing

I was creating themes for Nokia phones on 11.10 so I need an application to reduce the dimensions and size of a given image precisely, say X-KB and x*y dimensions. Is there any such application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of external applications; just install [nautilus-image-converter](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/nautilus-image-converter) image resize plugin to nautilus. It is a really great tool